# Why don't quick replies I set on Wit.ai work on facebook messenger when deployed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, wit.ai

I'm using Wit.ai to create a chatbot on facebook messenger. However, if I set quick replies for a certain user input, having deployed the bot and entering said input, I only see the text that the quick reply buttons are supposed to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the messenger exemple in the Node.js SDK.

This code does not support quickreplies. First, you can use my code to implement the needed feature in the `sendTextMessage` function:

```
const sendMessage = (id, message) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    recipient: { id },
    message: message,
  });
  const qs = 'access_token=' + encodeURIComponent(FB_PAGE_TOKEN);
  return fetch('https://graph.facebook.com/me/messages?' + qs, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body,
  })
  .then(rsp => rsp.json())
  .then(json => {
    if (json.error && json.error.message) {
      throw new Error(json.error.message);
    }
    return json;
  });
};

const sendTextMessage = (id, text, quickreplies) => {
  if(!quickreplies) return sendMessage(id, {text});

  if(quickreplies.length > 10) {
    throw new Error("Quickreplies are limited to 10");
  }

  let body = {text, quick_replies: []};
  quickreplies.forEach(qr => {
    body.quick_replies.push({
      content_type: "text",
      title: qr,
      payload: 'PAYLOAD' //Not necessary used but mandatory
    });
  });
  return sendMessage(id, body);
};
```

Second, you have to consider the quickreplies in the "send" action. Here is a very simple "send action" example:

```
const actions = {
  send({sessionId}, {text, quickreplies}) {
    const recipientId = sessions[sessionId].fbid;
    return sendTextMessage(recipientId, text, quickreplies);
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also, note that the messenger quickreplies are limited to 20 characters.